# Bootstrap 3 navbar doesn't expand on collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

After the million bootstrap navigation bars I've made, this one is just giving me headaches. My bootstrap navbar does not expand on collapse. I've tried updating the boostrap.min.js three times thinking it was the problem (since it was customized) however it did not work. I've also tried using the dist version of bootstrap 3.3.0 (released not too long ago) and it still did not work.

I've read many questions of similar issues and they all were resolved because the OP was missing js or wrote incorrect markup. I've looked over my markup many times and it seems right. Here we go:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primaryBlue">Sign In</a>
                    </div>
                <li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It collapses but doesn't expand once clicked. I don't use bootstrap glyphicons, in this example I'm using the navicon from font awesome. Does it look ok?

Comment: what is .navbar-master? Where is your css? Does navbar-master have a height and an overflow:hidden? Have you inspected it with Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: That is just my class for styling the form. I should note I've also tried using the example for the bootstrap docs. It doesn't have overflow hidden but I did configure a height using the customizer from bootstrap.

Comment: Since you are not sharing a minimal full example there's no way to know what the issue is. Remove your custom css, clear the cache, and see if that helps.

Comment: I changed it to navbar-default. It really doesn't matter, navbar-master only set a thicker border and background color.

Comment: Your markup works fine: http://www.bootply.com/pQO1yPxuat -- I'd guess it's how you've included the jquery and bootstrap files

Comment: I have no words right now, there was a typo in the js include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added JQuery to your project sometime you should add that at the top of you web page to work.

CDN

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll just mark this as the accepted answer. My include had a typo in it. It was easy to miss it.